# how to count unique records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large property database and I am trying to get the postcode for a specific property then get the first letter ( the region ) and then count all other properties in my database in that region.

What I am after:

Property postcode is `L21 5PU`

And I want to display a list of links:

Similar properties in

L1 (4)
L2 (5)
L23 (27) and so on

Here is where I am upto

```
$PC = 'L';

PCSearch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Property WHERE POSTCODE LIKE '$PC'")
```

But how do I count each property whose postcode begins with `$PC` ( L in this case ) and display a list of the postcodes with the number next to them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group by, something like

```
SELECT postcode , count(*) as property_count FROM property GROUP BY postcode
```

That will group all the post codes and give you a property count.

If you want to do partial matching, I believe you will have to run a loop for each partial postcode you want looked up and add a "where" clause in the above query.

```
.. WHERE postcode LIKE 'L%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT `postcode`, CONCAT(`postcode`, COUNT(`postcode`)) AS `output`
FROM `Property`
GROUP BY `postcode`
```

The column `output` should now contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with your SQL query, using three functions:

[SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

[COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)